# Using OG to create custom user profile - need to share content with selected group members. Does anyone know of a module that does this?

Tags: users, organic-groups

I'm creating a site using D7 with OG to create a custom user profile where the user's group is auto created upon registration.  Everything is working just as I want it to, but now I'm hitting a wall with a required feature.  I need to have a method of allowing a user to post an "update" and share it with all or select "followers" (I'm using the OG member feature as a user's followers) and have it show their updates on their "home" page (which is really their group's main page).  I was thinking of using private message for this, but it is giving me fits getting it to do what I want.  I was thinking an alternative method might be to create a content type for Update and allow the user to post these into their group - but then I need to add an additional layer on top of the inherent public/private filter.  What I'd really like to do is allow the user to select from a list of group members and have the specific update only visible to those members.

Does anyone know of a module that exists that would allow this?  I'm trying to avoid writing a custom module if at all possible.

Thanks!

Comment: so are you asking that content posted should be visible to group members only ?

Comment: That is easy - I'm talking an additional layer below that - where the user could specify to which members the content would be visible.